# What are some suggestions for using hdiutil (or other tools) for recovery of files from dmg image?

Tags: virtualbox, ddrescue

I am attempting to recover information from a USB using GNU ddrescue 1.18.1. I have completed the rescue operation output from the /dev/disk2s2 partition to a disk image file on a networked resource (.dmg). I have attempted to execute the following command:

```
hdiutil attach /Volumes/etc/photos.dmg -nomount
```

**Which presents this error information:**

> 2014-08-12 11:39:15.679 hdiutil[13866:1528817] Error loading
>   /Library/Plug-ins/DiskImages/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin:
>   dlopen(/Library/Plug-ins/DiskImages/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin,
>   262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Library/Plug-ins/DiskImages/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/VirtualPCDiskImagePlugin:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture 2014-08-12 11:39:15.680
>   hdiutil[13866:1528817] Cannot find function pointer
>   MacDiskImagePluginFactory for factory
>   7F1FD83E-6684-11D8-968F-000A957703C0 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn
>   0x7fd383c12db0
>   
>   (bundle, not loaded)

**NB: I was creating a Windows virtual-box image (writing) on the original USB drive when it fell and lost the physical connection. (after this event is when the USB stopped mounting)**

- Also, the Library Plugin mentioned in the error message may need to be reinstalled as I've updated the host OS of my machine.

**Questions**

- Are there other steps that I can try to read the files from the .dmg file? (just enough to recover photos to another disk)
- Are there any free software options that might help me take the recovery process further?
- I no longer use Virtual PC (switched to VirtualBox) but should I reinstall it at this point?

Setup:
MacOSX 10.10
ddrescue 1.18.1
VirtualBox 4.3.14